# how to retrieve entity on update in dynamics crm 2011

Tags: plugins, entity, dynamics-crm-2011

I am new to CRM and trying to write a plugin.

It's should be simple, but it's not.

For some reason I can't retrieve entity.
I know for sure that it is exists in database and ID is correct.

The code below....

Does anyone has any ideas why it is not working?
Thanks

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using System.ServiceModel;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using System.Collections;

namespace Copy_field
{
    public class Copy_field : IPlugin
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// A plugin copyies fields from Contact Entity to Case Entity. This allows display
        /// information about the client on case Entity and change it directly from Case Entity 
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>Register this plug-in on the Create case, update case and update of contact
        /// </remarks>
        /// 

        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext) serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

            ITracingService tracer = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

            Entity entity;

            if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
            {

                entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
                if (entity.LogicalName != "incident") { return; } 
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        //    tracer.Trace("1. THIS IS an/a: " + entity.LogicalName);
          //  tracer.Trace("2. Id: " + entity.Id);
   //         tracer.Trace("2.2 output parametersId: " + context.OutputParameters["id"].ToString());

            // if record exists - retrieve the entity

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ColumnSet cols = new ColumnSet(true);
        Entity yahhooo = service.Retrieve(entity.LogicalName, entity.Id, cols);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know its not working?

Comment: yes, your code does look like definitions.  So, JamesWood is correct in asking, how do you know it is not working?  Is your code not firing? Is it firing?  Do you get into the if block?  what values come back for `entity.Id` and `entity.LogicalName`? what else can you tell us? ;)

Answer (score 1):

don't forget that in update message , you only access to  filed's that you update(change) it...
you can write as in the following method to trace your code(line to line)

```
  public static void LogFile(string log)
    {
        try
        {
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\inventorylog_" + Guid.NewGuid() + ".txt");
            tw.Write(log);
            tw.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Be successful

Comment: This looks like a generic debugging technique.  How does it help the question as asked?

Comment: Wherever there is doubt that the condition code will be executed or not he can make it can be used. To realize that is target there is

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could give us a little bit more of information about it like, is it throwing any exception? My guess is that you are getting the following error:
 "The "yourentity" with id "yourentityid" does not exist in the database", if so you may be trying to retrieve a record on it's create on Pre-Operation pipeline.
Anyway, help us help you giving us more information.